# Tool to return HTML as string after injecting variables

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

### Context

I'm building a tool using React and one of it's functionalities is taking several user information through a form and returning a full HTML code for copying and pasting into an `.html` file.

I did use handlebars on a past project, but server side. I don't know how to implement something like this using only front-end code — I did read Handlebars documentation but couldn't understand it's usage.

In this question I'm using a very stripped down handlebars-like code as an example. The final code would have much more details.

### Example

I would have a template:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{ user.name }}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>I'm a {{ user.job }}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

The user would input it's name and job, let's say, John and Doctor.

and after clicking a button it would return:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>John</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>I'm a Doctor</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

This code would be production ready, so if the user copy-paste it on a `.html` file, it would work perfectly.

### The question

I thought about creating a template string with all the info and injecting it through good old javascript, but thought: there might be a better way to do this

(And more readable, as a huge HTML file written inside a template string, inside a function, isn't something too nice)

Are there any tools that can help me do that? Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

I believe a template string would work:

```js
const returnHTML = (title, name) => {
  return `<html>
            <head>
              <title>
                ${title}
              </title>
            </head>
            <body>
              <h2>
                Welcome, ${name}
               </h2>
            </body>
          </html>`;
   }
```

```html
<button onclick="document.write(returnHTML('hi', 'AJ'))">Insert</button>
```